# elastic search for string with quotes and colon

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a log entry in my elastic search results that looks like this

'source_volid': None

or

'source_volid': '71509e33-3a1f-4c5a-a0a3-e785ff92xxxx'

I happen to only want to find the entries with the uuid as a value

I can't get es to match anything other than source_volid, not matter what the search string and escapes are

I've tried
"source_volid': '"
"source_volid': '"
"source_volid\': \'"
and many others

no matter what it always matches
source_volid
which gives me every entry in the log, which includes the None values.

Comment: Give a example the documents.

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

When search for `source_volid: ""` it is going to match every document.

## Solution

Use the keyword in conjunction with a `bool + must_not` query this should do the trick.

```json
POST /_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"73887408"}}
{"source_volid":""}
{"index":{"_index":"73887408"}}
{"source_volid":"some data"}

GET /73887408/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "source_volid.keyword": ""
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

ps: Make sure that you index the field as a `keyword`

Here is the mapping I have.

```json
{
  "73887408": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "source_volid": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```